# Adding pvalue inside multiple boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm trying to add the p value to my boxplot and show inside my plot. I found something close on the Internet:

[image]

So far, I could get the pvalue and set it in the title, but it looks really bad.

Is it possible to create a box on the top right corner of my plot and show the p value for each data there?

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

boxplot(x = df, main = round(t.test(df)$p.value, digits=3))
boxplot(x = df1, main = round(t.test(df1)$p.value, digits=3))
boxplot(x = df2, main = round(t.test(df2)$p.value, digits=3))
boxplot(x = df3, main = round(t.test(df3)$p.value, digits=3))
```

Comment: After you've created a boxplot, then do something like `text(x, y, round(t.test(df3)$p.value, digits=3))`, where `x` and `y` are the coordinates of the upper right corner of the graph panel (which can be calculated programmatically from the data).

Comment: or mtext, `mtext(paste('p', format.pval(t.test(data)$p.value, eps = .001)), at = par('usr')[2], line = -1, adj = 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(448)
dat = data.frame(x = c(rnorm(20), rnorm(20,1,1)), y=rep(c("A","B"), each=20))

boxplot(dat$x ~ dat$y, xlim=c(0.5,3))
rect(2.85 - 0.2, max(dat$x) - 0.12, 2.85 + 0.2, max(dat$x) + 0.12)
text(2.85, max(dat$x), paste0("p < ", round(t.test(dat$x ~ dat$y)$p.value, 3)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use ggboxplot in ggpubr library

```
mycol <- c("#4682B4", "#DB7093")

p <- ggboxplot(df, x = 'mode', y = 'value',
             color = 'Type', palette = mycol,
             size = 0.6)

p1 <- p + stat_compare_means(aes(group = Type),method = 't.test', label = "p.signif", size = 3)
```

[image]